# Using ColumnTransformer with already fitted estimators

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

in order to preprocess data before handing it to my model to make predictions, I am using a ColumnTransformer. But the transformers I want to use are already fitted, I want to make predictions now and don't want to train anymore. My code:

```
features = pd.DataFrame(tokens)

num_attributes = ['frequency', 'relative_frequency', 'relative_first_occurrence']
cat_attributes = ["pos_tag"]

# reload already determined encoder
with open(ENCODER_SVM, 'rb') as f:
    cat_encoder = pickle.load(f)

with open(SCALER_SVM, 'rb') as f:
    scaler = pickle.load(f)

full_pipeline = ColumnTransformer([
    ("num", scaler, num_attributes),
    ("cat", cat_encoder, cat_attributes),
])

# transform categories and number attributes
# don't need to fit the data, because the objects were already fit,
# that is why they are loaded via pickle
transformed = full_pipeline.transform(features)
```

`scaler` is a fitted `StandardScaler` and `cat_encoder` is a fitted `OneHoteEncoder`. I am just loading the persisted python objects and reusing them. Because they are already fitted I call the `transform()` method instead of `fit_transform()`. For some reason the `ColumnTransformer` has to do some fitting or whatever anyway, because I get the error:

```
NotFittedError: This ColumnTransformer instance is not fitted yet. Call 'fit' with appropriate arguments before using this method.
```

But when calling `fit_transform()` the transformers seem to be fitted again, thus rendering the reloading of the python objects useless. This seems annoying as hell. Somehow most Machine Learning tutorials just teach you how to train models and ingnore the testing and prediction phases, at least the practical implementations. Could someone help me?

Comment: So instead of saving and loading the individual components, why dont just fit the ColumnTransformer once and load it next time?

Comment: Does this work? I will try it, thanks.

Comment: When I do that I get the error: "IndexError: positional indexers are out-of-bounds
"

Comment: How do you do `"that"`?

Comment: I am persisting the fitted ColumnTransformer and reload it instead of reloading the OneHoteEncoder and the StandardScaler respectively. I just followed your suggestion. But when doing so I get the mentioned error.

Comment: Ok, my training data actually had more columns, I just added dummy values for the missing columns and the code doesn't crash. I think I can work with this, thanks.

Comment: I also am particularly enjoying (#sarcasm) how OrdinalEncoder (both namespaces) will take a "mapping" or "categories" parameter at constuction, and then abs refuse to run until you call "fit", effectively discarding the categories you painstakingly fed it. :/  Yes, 5 years later.